# Redux state in reducer not up to date?

Tags: redux, react-redux, state, redux-thunk

I'm building an application using React/Redux, I have an array of products which are loaded to Redux state asynchronously and from which I would then like to pull individual products. However, the reducer I have written to do this isn't working as it is registering state as `null`. This is confusing me as calling `getState()` in the thunk action creator prior to returning the action and triggering the reducer is logging the correct state with the array of products.

Is this an error in my code or simply part of how redux state updates?

**ACTION CREATOR: getSingleProduct**

```
export const getSingleProduct = productName => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const action = { type: 'GET_SINGLE_PRODUCT', productName };
  if (!getState().products.length) return dispatch(getAllProducts())
    .then(() => {
      console.log('STATE IN ACTION CREATOR THEN BLOCK', getState());
      return dispatch(action);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
  else return action;
}
```

**REDUCER: currentProduct**

```
const currentProduct = (state = null, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_SINGLE_PRODUCT':
      console.log('STATE IN REDUCER', state);
      return state.products.filter(prod => prod.name.toLowerCase() === action.productName)[0];
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

***Console Log Output***

```
STATE IN ACTION CREATOR THEN BLOCK 
{ basket: Array(0), products: Array(6), currentProduct: null }


STATE IN REDUCER
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducer state was in fact up to date, the issue was a misunderstanding of how reducer state works. I was trying to utilise a dependent state which is not available from the `state` argument of the reducer. The resolution for me was to pass this information from a dependent state in on the action object.

**action**

```
export const getSingleProduct = (productName, products = []) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  let action = {
    type: 'GET_SINGLE_PRODUCT',
    productName,
    products: getState().products
  }
  if (!action.products.length) dispatch(getAllProducts())
    .then(() => {
      action = Object.assign({}, action, { products: getState().products });
      dispatch(action);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
  else return action;
}
```

**reducer**

```
const currentProduct = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_SINGLE_PRODUCT':
      const currentProduct = action.products.filter(prod => prod.name.toLowerCase() === action.productName)[0];
      return Object.assign({}, state, currentProduct);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

State is null cause you defined it as null on first function call.
console.log state after action complete and you see value run.
It is wrong to return modified state. Should return new state.

```
const currentProduct = (state = null, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case 'GET_SINGLE_PRODUCT':
    console.log('STATE IN REDUCER', state);
    const products = state.products.slice().filter(prod => prod.name.toLowerCase() === action.productName)[0];

    return { ...state, products } 
    break;
  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried swapping out my reducer for yours but it produces the same result. I'm not sure I fully understand the changes you've made, the `filter()` method is immutable so I'm not changing the state there and I'm not sure what the value of adding `slice()` is. Also using spread state in the returning object when state is null achieves what? Is it simply ignored?

Comment: @Josh i just little correct reducer. You can't see reducer value in console.log because state is `null` at this moment, try to `consoe.log` after action calls

Comment: thanks for the assistance. I've realised now what my fundamental issue was. I was trying to utilise a dependent `products` state in my `currentProduct` reducer. Instead I am now passing this into the reducer on the action object which is has resolved the issue.

Comment: Okay, nice, no problem